# Inflate custom widget in ListWidget - PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I am trying to design a list of items each of which is a custom widget (not necessarily though, I want to display an image and three texts in each item). 
In PyQt, the function *addItem* can be used to add an item to the list that takes as argument *QListWidgetItem*.

As such, I was trying to cast my custom defined widget to QListWidetItem with no success. I tried the following chunk of code:

```
listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
item = QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
custom_item = CustomWidget()
listWidget.addItem(item)
listWidget.setItemWidget(item, item_widget)
```

The list displays an empty list, and this is expected since I am never inflating the custom_item with the above code. How to fix this in PyQT?

I am not sure, but the custom widget might be relevant:

```
class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, user):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.user = user
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 211, 41))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.UserImage = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.UserImage.setText("This is an Image")
        self.UserImage.setObjectName("UserImage")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.UserImage)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.UserName = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.UserName.setText("My name is jeff")
        self.UserName.setObjectName("UserName")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.UserName)
        self.UserStatus = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.UserStatus.setText("I am available")
        self.UserStatus.setObjectName("UserStatus")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.UserStatus)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout.setStretch(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I notice from your code is that the widget is not built correctly, `self.horizontalLayout` is the main widget but it has no parent so it will never be drawn, besides that you can avoid that widget. On the other hand, you must set the size of the item with `setSizeHint()`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class CustomWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 211, 41))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.UserImage = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.UserImage.setText("This is an Image")
        self.UserImage.setObjectName("UserImage")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.UserImage)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.UserName = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.UserName.setText("My name is jeff")
        self.UserName.setObjectName("UserName")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.UserName)
        self.UserStatus = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.UserStatus.setText("I am available")
        self.UserStatus.setObjectName("UserStatus")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.UserStatus)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout.setStretch(1, 3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(listWidget)
    item_widget = CustomWidget("user")
    listWidget.addItem(item)
    listWidget.setItemWidget(item, item_widget)
    item.setSizeHint(item_widget.sizeHint())
    listWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]